# Punctuation of the phrase "in this regard"

Tags: commas

Should there be a comma after the phrase "in this regard", when the phrase is used in the beginning of a sentence?

Eg: In this regard it is submitted that the assessment took place before the amendment of the said legal provisions.

Answer (score 3):

A comma would be considered correct usage.

If starting the sentence with a prepositional phrase, then a comma should separate the phrase from the rest of the sentence.

> In this regard, it is submitted that the assessment took place before the amendment of the said legal provisions.

This [page](http://www.spwickstrom.com/prepositions/) has some good examples of how to use prepositions and prepositional phrases.

Answer (score 1):

The comma may be present or absent in this case.